# Naming IPA / APK output of Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, tfs, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac using Xamarin for a cross platform mobile application.

Currently the IPA/APK filename is just the project name. However for testing purposes it'd be handy if we could suffix the version on to this. In iOS land I normally would write a bash script as a post build trigger that performed some manipulation on the filename of the IPA. However I'm unsure what the best approach is on xamarin? I'm also using TFS to trigger CI builds and we'd like those to be suffixed with the version too.

For instance:

SampleApp_1.3.APK and SamepleApp_1.3.IPA

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a different output name for any target in Options:
[image]

Comment: Is there a variable I can place here that will output the version number of the application though? Ideally I'd dynamically want to name the IPA based on the android manifest version number and iOS plist version number.

Comment: you can add a post build script to rename it, you can add a different script for each targer